# Get current tab selection HTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension and I need to read the HTML code of the current selection in background.html
I can get the text selection from background.html:

```
function(info,tab) {
    var text = info.selectionText;
}
```

But I need the HTML code. From inside background.html I tried:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var container = range.commonAncestorContainer;
var html = container.innerHTML
```

But I believe I can't access the window object from inside background ...

I did read SpikeX post: [Get page selection including HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461989/get-page-selection-including-html) but not couldn't find the source code he's referring to...

Thanks!

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to html content with chrome.tabs.executeScript . See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

Comment: Thanks anfilat, I did that and it worked (injecting the JS from the background page) basically I had to add a listener and then inject the script:       chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onSelection);
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"content.js",allFrames:true});

Answer (score 0):

I have once written a user JavaScript for Opera inspired by the "view selection source" functionality from Mozila/Firefox. [You can read about it and grab the code here](http://blog.webkitchen.cz/view-selection-source).

**Edit:**
Now when I read the question you linked I realized that I actually also wrote the first Chrome extension mentioned in the answer. It was also based on that script. However, it stopped working with some Chrome update and I never look into that issue. Nevertheless, it should be pretty easy to fix.

Comment: thanks jkbr - I read the code and I guess my problem is in this area: var sel = findSelection(window); ... anything I try including the aforementioned doesn't return anything on background.html. I believe that's my issue, I cannot get window.getSelection() from the background.html page - once I get that I know how to get the HTML using range ..