# Get Selection DOM in chrome extension contextmenu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to get the DOM I select by `ContextMenu` in Chrome Extension.

Code:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  // the info.selectionText just the text, don not contains html.
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Demo",
  contexts: ["selection"],
  id: "demo"
});
```

but the info.selectionText don't contains the HTML DOM. Is there any way to get the selection dom in Chrome extension contextMenu?. Please suggest. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get page selection including HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461989/get-page-selection-including-html)

Answer (score 6):

To access the selection, you will need to inject a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) into the page.

There, you can call `getSelection()` to get a [`Selection` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and play with ranges in it to extract the DOM you need.

```
// "activeTab" permission is sufficient for this:
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "getDOM.js"})
});
```

getDOM.js:

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
// extract the information you need
// if needed, return it to the main script with messaging
```

You may want to take a look at [Messaging docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Answer (score 0):

If you want just selected text from context menu than you can do it by following code

```
function getClickHandler() {
    return function(info, tab) {
      // info.selectionText contain selected text when right clicking
      console.log(info.selectionText);
    };
  };


/**
 * Create a context menu which will only when text is selected.
 */
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Get Text!",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["selection"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler()
});
```

Comment: if I want to get the clicked DOM, how can I change the code to work?

Comment: @Gideon I think you should try logging "info" variable passed along getClickHandler()

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it in v3 manifest:

```
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async (info, tab) => {
  const tabId = tab?.id;

  if (tabId && info.menuItemId === 'my menu item' && info.selectionText) {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
      {
        func: () => {
          const selection = window.getSelection();
          const range = selection?.getRangeAt(0);
          if (range) {
            const clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
            return div.innerHTML;
          }
        },
        target: {
          tabId,
        },
      },
      (result) => {
        const html = result[0].result;
        // do something with `html`
      },
    );
  }
});
```

This requires both `scripting` and `activeTab` permissions.