# How do I put the selected text/link in my chrome extension's page context menu?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I selected some text, the context menu title is updated. For instance:

[image]

Is it possible to do this as an extension developer?

My current code:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title":"I WANT THIS UPDATED",
  "contexts":["browser_action"],
  "onclick":function(info, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'https://www.facebook.com/'});
  }
});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but not for `browser_action` context.

The screenshot you're showing is for `selection` context.

Quoting the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contextMenus#method-create):

> When the context is `'selection'`, you can use `%s` within the string to show the selected text. For example, if this parameter's value is "Translate '%s' to Pig Latin" and the user selects the word "cool", the context menu item for the selection is "Translate 'cool' to Pig Latin".

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31379357/934239) for more info on context types.

Comment: what if I want to make it more customized? For instance, if I select something, it's the text, but if not, it's something else?

Comment: `selection` context only applies when something is selected. Perhaps you're looking for `page` context, which can specify a different menu.

Comment: good idea, so I think I should use different context menu types to do this.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Added a link to an old answer of mine regarding contexts. So possibly you want `all` instead of `page`.