# Using Selection as a Variable in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to access user-selected text from a context menu in a Chrome extension.

In case my explanation isn't clear, here's the basic use-case.

1. User selects text on page
2. User right-clicks selection and left-clicks extension from context menu
3. Selected text is accessed by extension and set as `var`
4. `var` is printed

Step 3 is what I'm stuck on.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Selection DOM in chrome extension contextmenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211174/get-selection-dom-in-chrome-extension-contextmenu)

Comment: Use google to see more examples: [stackoverflow chrome extension get selected text in context menu](https://www.google.com/#q=stackoverflow+chrome+extension+get+selected+text+in+context+menu)