# Selected text into right click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there another way to get highlighted text(retain line breaks)?

```
var newProspect = function(string){
    console.log(string.selectionText);
 };

chrome.contextMenus.create({
 title: "New Prospect",
 contexts:["all"],
 onclick: newProspect
});
```

Comment: [Get Selection DOM in chrome extension contextmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28215694)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newProspect = function(string){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(
    {
      code: "window.getSelection().toString(); ",
    },
    function (selection) {
      var selectionText = selection[0]
    }
  );
};

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "New Prospect",
  contexts: ["selection"],
  onclick: newProspect,
});
```